# error: no such file or directory codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Sorry for the few details or spelling mistakes, because I'm new to programming
I downloaded a code for the game ready from one of the sites and the code I made sure of it does not have any errors, as I am the owner of the code that ran it in his YouTube lesson

And when I run the code, this message appears to me. I downloaded all the add-ons, but
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEHZD.jpg)
the problem remained the same. I hope you can help me

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Post text instead.

Comment: Looks like it can't find the compiler

Comment: Seems like your one of the header file is not right

Comment: It appears that you have not set the compiler toolchain with relative paths or even have not installed a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons for this problem. For example,

- Incorrect installation of the compiler, as a result of which it may not be able to find some of the header files.
- Another thing can be the directory/folder the file is in. If the folder's or file's name is not fully written in English (numbers and a few special characters are also allowed), such a problem could arise.